# How to get closed form solution for this cubic equation with parameter

Tags: equation-solving

I am new to Mathematica and I was trying to get closed form equation of this equation by $d$:

$$9d^3 - 18d^2 - 12d + 8t = 0, \quad t>1.$$

I tried to get the solution by using $\textbf{Solve}$ as follows:

```
eqns = And @@ {9*d^3 - 18*t*d^2 - 12 d + 8 t == 0, t > 1}

Solve[eqns, d]
```

The output gives me:

```
{{d -> ConditionalExpression[
    Root[8 t - 12 #1 - 18 t #1^2 + 9 #1^3 &, 1], t > 1]}, {d -> 
   ConditionalExpression[Root[8 t - 12 #1 - 18 t #1^2 + 9 #1^3 &, 2], 
    t > 1]}, {d -> 
   ConditionalExpression[Root[8 t - 12 #1 - 18 t #1^2 + 9 #1^3 &, 3], 
    t > 1]}}
```

Here comes my confusion. First, I am not sure what this $\textbf{Root}$ and # symbol exactly implies. I check some other answers in this site which said use $\textbf{ToRadicals}$. But this gives me answers that are all complex numbers.

Also, this answer is wrong as if I solve this equation with some exact value for $t$ (eg. $t=2$), it clearly has real answers:

```
Reduce[9*d^3 - 36*d^2 - 12*d + 16 == 0, d]
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: The output of `Reduce[9*d^3 - 36*d^2 - 12*d + 16 == 0, d] // ToRadicals` is complex valued

Comment: It appears there's an extra factor of `t` in the `d^2` term for the code you provided while there isn't one in the formatted equation.  Which one is the right one?  Judging from your later example with $18*2 = 36$ as the coefficient on the `d^2` term, I would assume the inclusion of the `t` factor is the correct form.

Comment: Not sure entirely what you meant, but note that when writing the roots of a cubic equation in terms of radicals, complex numbers are generally unavoidable *even if the the actual roots are real*. This is known as [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

Comment: Thank you all for the great comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am leaving this here as an extended comment before I vote to close the question.

Essentially, the following is telling you that all commands give you the same result, ergo there's no tension.

```
eqn = 9*d^3 - 18*t*d^2 - 12 d + 8 t;
sltn2 = Solve[(eqn /. t -> 2) == 0, d] // ToRadicals;
sltn = Assuming[{t ∈ Reals, t > 1}, 
    Simplify[Solve[9*d^3 - 18*t*d^2 - 12 d + 8 t == 0, d]]] // 
   ToRadicals;
SortBy[(sltn /. t -> 2) // Expand, Max]
SortBy[sltn2 // Expand, Max]
SortBy[List[
  ToRules[(Reduce[(eqn /. t -> 2) == 0, d]) // ToRadicals // 
    Expand]], Max]
```

> [image: out]

**Edit** following what @Nasser suggested in the comments section, we can check if all the answers for `t=2` to `t=50` are real numbers in the following manner:

```
Internal`RealValuedNumericQ /@ (Values[
   Table[(sltn // N), {t, 2, 50}] // Chop // Flatten])
```

> [image: true]

If you want, you can have a look

```
Grid@Partition[MatrixForm /@ Table[(sltn // N), {t, 2, 50}] // Chop, 
  10]
```

> [image: vqlues]